# Recovery from dns lookup failure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I'm trying to check 22,800+ urls from a 2012 database to find out which ones are still valid. I'm using urllib in Python 3.8 in PyCharm. It makes it through the first 47 urls which are in a text file that I read in. Then it crashes when the host can't be found.

Here's the error output:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1350, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
self.sock = self._create_connection(
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/rmcape/PycharmProjects/first/venv/validateURLs.py", line 19, in 
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1379, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Users\rmcape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1353, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed>

---

How can I detect the DNS lookup failure and recover from it and continue on to the next URL in the file? Is there some other library that I should be using? I've googled about everything I can think of.
Thanks for any help.

---

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/python
#
#validateURLs.py
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import responses
import socket

f = open("updatedURLs.txt", "r")
site=f.readline()
siteCount=1
errorCount=0
while site:
    site=site.strip()
    req = urllib.request.Request(site)
    try:
        resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respo=str(resp.getcode())
        result = "("+str(siteCount)+") "+respo+" ==> "+site
        print(result)
            #print(siteCount, site, resp.getcode())
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        errorCount=errorCount+1
        result="("+str(siteCount)+") "+str(e.code)+" ==> "+site
        print(result)
        print("errorCount = "+str(errorCount))
    site=f.readline()
    siteCount=siteCount+1
print(errorCount)
print("Done")
```

Comment: You're already 
 `except`ing HTTPErrors, why not do the same for `URLError`s as well?

Comment: Not sure what that would look like. A try: xxx except xxx except xxx ?

Comment: Yep, some examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-exception-handling-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks! That got me on the right track. It is taking a long time to process the 22,800+ URLs. I also dropped the e.code and just did e

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?:

```
#!/bin/python
#
#validateURLs.py
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import responses
import socket

f = open("updatedURLs.txt", "r")
site=f.readline()
siteCount=1
errorCount=0
while site:
    site=site.strip()
    req = urllib.request.Request(site)
    try:
        resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respo=str(resp.getcode())
        result = "("+str(siteCount)+") "+respo+" ==> "+site
        print(result)
            #print(siteCount, site, resp.getcode())
    except Exception as e:
        errorCount=errorCount+1
        result="("+str(siteCount)+") "+str(e)+" ==> "+site
        print(result)
        print("errorCount = "+str(errorCount))
    else:
        site=f.readline()
        siteCount=siteCount+1
print(errorCount)
print("Done")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It got stuck in a loop after 4 urls.